# Embedding the absolute Galois group of $ \mathbf Q_p $ into that of $ \mathbf Q $

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

It is mentioned, in passing, in many sources that the restriction map $ \textrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbf Q_p}/\mathbf Q_p) \to \textrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbf Q}/\mathbf Q) $ is an embedding, that is, an element of the absolute Galois group of $ \mathbf Q_p $ is completely determined by its action on the algebraic numbers. I have been trying to prove this statement, to no avail...

I suspect that one might take a monic polynomial $ f \in \mathbf Q_p[X] $, and approximate it closely by a sequence of monic polynomials $ f_n \in \mathbf Q[X] $. Hopefully, as the sup-norm difference between the polynomials gets smaller, so do their roots get closer together - however, I have not been able to turn this into a rigorous argument. How would you go about proving this fact?

Related: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374698/why-the-action-of-mathrmgal-overline-mathbb-q-p-mathbb-q-p-on-overli)

Comment: The key phrase that no one below has seemed to mention is 'Krasner's lemma' which shows that the completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ at a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ lying over $p$ is $\mathbb{C}_p$. This, in particular, shows that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is (under the embedding corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$) dense in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Since the elements of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ act continuously on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ density implies the restriction map $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\to G_\mathbb{Q}$ is injective.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there is an isomorphism between $G_{\mathbb Q_p}$ and the *decomposition group* $D_\mathfrak p$ of elements of $G_\mathbb Q$ which fix $\mathfrak p$ (where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime above $p$). In particular, this embedding is only well defined up to conjugation, or alternatively after fixing an embedding $\overline{\mathbb Q}\hookrightarrow\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R. Raylor gives an outline as follows: the absolute value $|\cdot |_p$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ has a unique extension to an absolute value on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and $G_p:=\textrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb Q_p}/\mathbb Q_p)$ is identified with the group of automorphisms of 
$\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ which preserve $|\cdot |_p$, and it easy to see that this is the group of continuous automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. Thus we obtain, for each embedding $\overline{Q}\hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ a closed embedding $G_p\hookrightarrow \textrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: I have thought about this approach, but I could not see why the resulting map would be an embedding - is $ \bar{\mathbf Q} $ dense in $ \bar{\mathbf Q_p} $?

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}_p$, the completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$.

Comment: How would one prove this claim?

Comment: See the proof [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=SMztCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=Is+the+algebraic+closure+of+Q+dense+in+the+algebraic+closure+of+Q_p?&source=bl&ots=fvuL2STVGi&sig=3J6_mqtLgYEHS9EIGMXaaZC3Iqk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpoILnjMbPAhVHPxQKHSdADpwQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=Is%20the%20algebraic%20closure%20of%20Q%20dense%20in%20the%20algebraic%20closure%20of%20Q_p%3F&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

If $P \in \Bbb Q_p[X]$ is a degree $n$ polynomial with $n$ roots $x_i$, consider the map $\phi_P$ that takes a degree $n-1$ polynomial $Q$ and outputs the degree $n-1$ polynomial $\prod_i (Y - Q(x_i)) - Y^n$.

It turns out that the Jacobian of $\phi_P$ at $Q=X$ is the discriminant of $P$ (the discriminant has to divide it, then you can check that the degrees coincide).

If this discriminant is nonzero (so if $P$ has distinct roots) this entails that there are neighbourhoods of $Q = X$ and of $P$ where $\phi_P$ is a local homeomorphism.

In particular, if $P$ is the minimal polynomial of some $x \in \overline {\Bbb Q_p}$ then every polynomial close enough to $P$ is a $\phi_P(Q)$ for some $Q$, which is an annihilating polynomial of the $Q(x_i) \in \Bbb Q_p(x_i)$.

In fact it would be great if $\phi_P(Q)$ was the minimal polynomial of $Q(x_1)$, because then the inclusion $\Bbb Q_p(Q(x_1)) \subset \Bbb Q_p(x_1)$ must be an equality and then we can just pick $Q$ such that $\phi_P(Q)$ is a rational approximation of $P$.

If it's not the minimal polynomial of $Q(x_1)$ then we must have a link between $\{1 ; Q(x_1) ; Q(x_1^2) ; \ldots Q(x_1^{n-1})\}$, so some big determinant whose entries are polynomials in the coefficients of $P$ and $Q$ is zero.

Since the determinant is continuous and is nonzero for $Q = X$, it stays nonzero for $Q$ close enough to $X$.

Then you have a small neighbourhood of $P$ where all the splitting fields are the same. In particular you can always get a rational appoximation of $P$ that has the same splitting field as $P$.

This shows that $\overline{\Bbb Q_p} = \Bbb Q_p \overline {\Bbb Q}$